# angularJS orderBy not reflected in original scope

Tags: angularjs

so I have a scope.data with an array of my objects. The data of that array is beeing displayed in a table and it is orderedBy x property. The display in the table works perfectly but the scope.data object its self is not sorted to reflect what the table is showing... Is there any way to get that object also sort as the sorting options?

Comment: I've answered why it's not working, however, if you include some code or more details, I might be able to tell you specifically how to sort that array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of applying the filter to scope.data in your template, you could apply the filter in your controller instead:

**Instead of**:

Controller:

```
$scope.data = [data array];
```

Template:

```
{{ data | orderBy:x }}
```

**Change to**:

Controller:

```
// Inject $filter into controller
$scope.data = $filter('orderBy')('x');
```

Template:

```
{{ data }}
```

**Data binding**:

If your `data` array was passed in, you can handle updates by setting up a watch function to check if the original array changes, and then automatically applying to the current $scope.data property.

Comment: Just FYI, you can also inject the orderBy filter itself, should you want to be more specific about the actual dependency:  `function MyCtrl($scope, orderByFilter) {  $scope.sortedData = orderByFilter($scope.data, 'x'); `

Comment: the function call to $filter didn't worked for me. I used `$scope.data = $filter('orderBy')($scope.data, 'x');`

Comment: What if my array has children? how can I order the parent and the children?

Answer (score 3):

OrderBy does not sort the scope's variable, instead it sorts the way it is displayed. You will need to sort the array in javascript if you want it to change in the $scope.